# Multiyplying a higher order functions result

Tags: haskell

Im trying to double the result of suming a list, but i cant figure out why this is wrong .

```
sumDoubles =map(2*)(foldr (+) 0 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have calculated the sum of the list (`Foldable`), then this is a number, so you can simply multiply with `2`, so:

```
sumDoubles :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a
sumDoubles = (2 *) . sum
```

A `map` is used to map each element in a list, but summing up a list, will result in a *scalar* number, so mapping makes no sense.